# A local diffeomorphism between Lie Algebra and Lie Group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie Algebra and $G$ be the associated connected, simply connected Lie group. It is known that $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Now let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and define $f:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ by $f(a_1e_1+\dots+a_ne_n)=\exp(a_1e_1)\dots\exp(a_ne_n)$. It is clamed that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism (for example in the proof of [lemma 3, theorem 3.1](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/SUGRA/Kobayashi.pdf)). How do we prove this?

I thought of using the differential $df$, but I'm not sure how to calculate $df$ and how to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is a vector space, so you can essentially think of this $f$ as a parametrization and compute partial derivatives. But they said that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism only in a neighborhood of $0 \in \mathfrak{g}$. So $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial e_i}(0) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} f(te_i) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp(te_i) = e_i. 
 $$Since $$\left\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial e_1}(0),\ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial e_n}(0) \right\} = \{e_1,\ldots, e_n  \}$$is linearly independent, the Inverse Function Theorem says that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism in some neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to prove that $\frac{d}{dt}_{t=0}\exp(te_i)=e_i$?

Comment: This is the definition of $\exp$ as a flow. Nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Left multiplication $L_g:G\to G$ is a local diffeomorphism for each $g \in G$, hence we have

$$
f(a^ie_i) \;\; =\;\; \prod_{i=1}^n L_{\exp(a^ie_i)} \;\; =\;\; L_{\exp(a^1e_1)} \circ \ldots \circ L_{\exp(a^ne_n)}.
$$

Comment: Left multiplication is a global diffeomorphism. Have you really addressed the question?